# R deducer error with .jcall

Tags: java, r, macos, deducer

Recently I installed latest R (3.1) and RStudio (0.98) on Mac.  While starting deducer() I get the following error.

```
> deducer()
Error in .jcall(.deducer, , "startNoJGR") :
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I get the same error whether I start deducer from terminal or RStudio. On googling I didn't find much info either and any help is much appreciated.

```
r> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin10.8.0                
system         x86_64, darwin10.8.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2014                        
month          04                          
day            10                          
svn rev        65387                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance

r> library("Deducer")
r> deducer()
Error in .jcall(.deducer, , "startNoJGR") : 
  RcallMethod: cannot determine object class

terminal> java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac one can only kick-off deducer from JGR env and all goes well. See Ian's reply at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/deducer/H7rqPFE9qY8

Answer (score 0):

I have run in to the same/similar problem. The best thing would be to launch JGR and enable the Deducer and Deducer Extras from JFG package manager as described in the Wiki link bellow for deducer.

[Deducer Mac OS Installation and usage.](http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.MacOSXInstallation)

I created a small R script the contains the code to launch JGR (the fours lines of code)

```
Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)
library(JGR)
Sys.unsetenv("NOAWT")
JGR()
```

and in the Package manager for JGR, checked the **load** and **default** check boxes for **Deducer** and **Deducer Extras**.